# SASS and Compass on Heroku - What is the best approach

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sass, compass-sass

This is **not** a question on how to implement Compass and SASS on Heroku, as that was fairly simple to implement:  http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-compass

I have my doubts about this solution, however.

The other solution is to add `Compass.configuration.sass_options={:never_update=>true}` to the production config and make sure the compiled CSS is in source control and the public folder.  Then, make sure the CSS is recompiled before every git push.

I don't like the idea of adding compiled CSS to source, but I also don't like the idea of recompiling the CSS every time the server is hit.

I can't seem to find any information regarding how often the CSS would be compiled or how long files are kept in the tmp folder.  I read somewhere that they are stored for the duration of the request, but I also read contradicting information that they are stored for the life-cycle of the **application**.

Which of the above two solutions would you choose?  Is there a third solution that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not like the idea of committing CSS to your source? Getting Sass AND Compass to play nice, at Heroku has been a constant issue that's not worth the time (for me) to solve.

Compile locally, and ship the CSS with your source. Save time :)